# Publish game in portuguese language on AirConsole

Tags: airconsole

It's possible publish a game in portuguese language on AirConsole, or is required be in english?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of Portuguese speaking users on AirConsole is just a low percentage. The primary language on AirConsole is english. The games should be therefore also in english to reach as many players as possible.
A second option to offer the game in another language is of course no problem.